# C++/C++11/C++0x in application to Reverse-engineering

Tags: c++

Is there any libraries for Reverse engineering/exploitation for the C++11/C++/C programming language ? I am currently learning C based languages and would like to know if there are any libraries for this kind of trade.

Answer (score 4):

Since C and C++ is compiled to machine code during compilation you'll want to learn assembly opcodes and how to use tools such as debuggers, pe editors and so on. It really depends what you want to be able to reverse engineer.

Get yourself a book which covers these sort of topics:
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Reversing-Secrets-Engineering-Eldad-Eilam/dp/0764574817/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1403987309&sr=1-1&keywords=secrets+of+reverse+engineering